# Answering "$f \in I$ or $g \in I$" via single ideal membership test

Tags: polynomials, ideals

I am interested whether the question
$$
\text{Given polynomials } f,g \in K[X] \text{ and an ideal } I \subseteq K[X] \text{, does } f \in I \text{ or } g \in I \text{ hold?}
$$
can be answered with a single ideal membership test.

I know that if the "or" was replaced by an "and", then the question can be answered by checking whether $fy + gz \in I$ with new indeterminates $y,z$.

Is anybody aware of any results in this case?

Comment: If $I$ is a prime ideal, then $fg\in I$ is equivalent to $f\in I$ or $g\in I$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot assume that $I$ is prime. So I would be interested in results for arbitrary ideals. Should have probably mentioned that - sorry.